# How to connect Asp.Nets database with my own context?

Tags: c#, .net, database, dbcontext

I'm trying to build an application in Mvc with Individual User Accounts, and I'm trying to connect the automatically generated database with my own context.
The problem I have when I trying to create a view of my Create method I get this errormessage:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to
>   retrieve metadata for 'Projekt_Dejtingsida.Models.Messages' is not
>   valid. The navigation property 'ApplicationUser' was not found on the
>   dependent type 'Projekt_Dejtsida.Models.Messages'. The Name value
>   should be a valid navigation property name.

Please help a beginner out!

Here are the models I'm using:

I have already tried the `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method, but it didn't work...

```
public class Messages {
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Receiver { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You can't send a message without a content")]
    [StringLength(300, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Your message should be between 3 and 300 characters")]
    public string MessageContent { get; set; }
} 

public class FriendRequests {
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser RequestTo { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser RequestFrom { get; set; }
    public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
}

public class Profile {
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Messages> MyMessages { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the DbContext:

```
public class DatesiteContext : DbContext {

    public DatesiteContext() : base() { }       

    public DbSet<FriendRequests> Requests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the MessageController

```
[Authorize]
public class MessageController : Controller
{
    // GET: Message
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        var db = new DatesiteContext();
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var msgs = db.Messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == userId);

        return View(new MessageViewModel {
            Sender = msgs.Sender,
            Receiver = msgs.Receiver,
            MessageContent = msgs.MessageContent
        });
    }

    public ActionResult Create(MessageViewModel model) {
        DatesiteContext db = new DatesiteContext();

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var msgs = db.Messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == userId);

        if (msgs == null) {
            db.Messages.Add(new Messages {
                Id = userId,
                Sender = msgs.Sender,
                Receiver = msgs.Receiver,
                MessageContent = msgs.MessageContent
            });
        } else {
            msgs.Sender = model.Sender;
            msgs.Receiver = model.Receiver;
            msgs.MessageContent = model.MessageContent;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `ApplicationUser` class defined? If your `ApplicationUser` class is not an EF entity then you cannot use it as a navigation property.

Comment: EF goes through your entities and interprets `virtual` properties as navigation properties to other entities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships